# Flowtype/Typescript general purpose get property

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, flowtype

Is there any way to properly type check the following code in either flow or typescript?:

```
type A = {
    x: string
}
type B = {
    y: string
}
function get(obj, prop) {
    return obj[prop];
}
const a: A = { x: 'x' }
const b: B = { y: 'y' }

get(a, 'x') // should type check
get(b, 'y') // should type check
get(a, 'y') // should NOT type check
get(b, 'x') // should NOT type check
```

Where `get` is a general purpose function for `obj` of any type. Can we annotate the code in a way that flow will check if `obj` has `prop`?

The main use case is writing a general purpose get function for deep properties. Something with similar functionality as [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs#get). I'm trying to avoid this situation:

```
if (a && a.b && a.b.c && a.b.c.d === 'blah') { ... }
```

### EDIT:

As mentioned by @vkurchatkin, we can use `$Keys`. But I can only get that to work with a getter function that is 1 level deep. How do we type the following function:

```
get<T: {}>(obj: T, prop1: $Keys<T>, prop2: /* ! */): /* ! */ { ... }
```

### EDIT 2:

I have written the following so far:

```
type A = {
    x: B
}

type B = {
    y: string
}

type GetDeep<T: {}, U, V> = Helper<T, U, V, Get<T, U>, Get<U, V>>

type Helper<T, U, V,   W, X> = (obj: T, a: $Keys<T>, b: $Keys<U>) => V

type Get<T, U> = (obj: T, a: $Keys<T>) => U;

// NOTE: here if I replace GetDeep<*, B, *> with GetDeep<*, *, *>
//       then it wrongly type checks everything
const getDeep: GetDeep<*, B, *> = (obj, a, b) => {
    return obj[a][b];
}

var va: A = {
    x: {y: 'abc'}
}

getDeep(va, 'x', 'y'); // ok
getDeep(va, 'x', 'z'); // error
```

It looks like in `type Get<T, U> = (obj: T, a: $Keys<T>) => U`, `U` is not the type of the value of `obj[a]`.

Comment: That kind of dynamic key programming don't mix well with static analysis. The path strings could come from runtime values after all.

Comment: given that I'm using literal values (`get(a,'x')`) is there any way to avoid writing that long `if` statement with typechecking?

Comment: No magical way. The easiest would be using a try catch abstraction but that would be a bit slower. Something like  if (Try(() => a.b.c.d)() === 'blah')

Comment: Alternatively, you can use an Option abstraction:  https://github.com/AlexGalays/option.ts

Option(a).map(a => a.b).map(b => b.c).map(c => c.d)()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with Flow:

```
function get<T: {}>(obj: T, prop: $Keys<T>) {
    return obj[prop];
}
```

Unfortunately, returned type is inferred as `any`. Flow has currently has `$PropertyType` in the works, so I believe this should be possible in the future (it doesn't work as expected yet):

```
function get<T: {}, P: $Keys<T>>(obj: T, prop: P): $PropertyType<T, P> {
    return obj[prop];
}
```

With this type you will be able to go two levels deep:

```
function getDeep<
    T: {},
    P: $Keys<T>,
    R: $PropertyType<T, P>,
    P2: $Keys<R>
  >(obj: T, a: P, b: P2): $PropertyType<R, P2> {
    return obj[a][b];
}
```

Or make something composable.

Comment: I found in [Advanced features in Flow](http://sitr.us/2015/05/31/advanced-features-in-flow.html#enumt) they are using `$Enum` instead of `$Keys`. Is there a difference? Also I know `$` features are not public but where can I find a list of them?

Comment: [Looks like `$Keys` is the new `$Enum` which is deprecated](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/326ce0e85b8a8b116cd1500193077cc4a87a7954/src/typing/type_annotation.ml#L247)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but one thing is still not clear. How do you write a get function that takes 2 prop names: `get(obj, prop1, prop2)`, that is, if `obj: T` and `prop1: $Keys<T>` then what is `prop2`?

Comment: There currently isn't a way to type that. However, I've brought it up with the team.

Comment: @james if you've opened an issue or some way for us to track the progress of this feature, please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

> Where get is a general purpose function for obj of any type. Can we annotate the code in a way that flow will check if obj has prop

You can't do that with TypeScript.

> Something with similar functionality as _.get

It would be much easier if safe navigation operator becomes available : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16

However the JavaScript committee needs to get on it and as far as I can see its sadly not being championed by anyone.

Till then I've also done `a && a.b` etc.

## More

A slow function I've used sometimes when cleaning up other peoples code:

```
export function safe<T>(action: () => T): T | undefined {
    try {
        return action();
    }
    catch (ex) {
        return undefined;
    }
}

// Usage
let c = safe(()=>a.b.c);
```

Comment: "You can't do that with flow or TypeScript."

See vkurchatkin's answer